# Select columnName,* from table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am a newbie in Oracle SQL, though I have experience in SQL Server.

In SQL Server, to select the rows from a table with a particular column in front:

```
select columnName,* from tableName
```

In Oracle:

```
select columnName,* from tableName
```

gives error **ORA-00936: missing expression**, as below:

[image]

Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't view images, but here's what I think you need:

```
select t.column_name, t.*
from table_name t
```

i.e. you should prefix that particular column name with a table alias ("t"), and then use the same alias with the asterisk ("t.*") to retrieve all table columns.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, if you need to view a column but also all columns, you need to define an alias for the table.

```
Select columnName, A.* 
from tableName A;
```

Answer (score 1):

few things we need to keep it in mind

1. Alias name in sql - used to derive the individual column name via select query
2. When you are going to use *[select all] you don't have to worry about the alias name
3. But when you try to pull all the columns and some specific fields you want to filter then you should go for "Alias"
4. Alias its object key to refer the inter column

   select stu.studentName,stu.* from student **stu**;